# Yii2 Active Form 2 Layout in 1 page

Tags: php, forms, layout, yii2

I'm using Active Form for inserting data in Yii2.

The default layout for the active form is Vertical Layout (Standard Layout) which show the `label` on top of the `textfield`.

Ss there a way to use 2 layouts in the same page?

In my case, I want to use Standard Layout which have Inline Layout in some 'textfield' part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use nested layouts:

```
<?php $this->beginContent('@app/views/layouts/base.php'); ?>

...child layout content here...

<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

More information is available in [according official docs section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#nested-layouts).